# Run PHP file in Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

I need some hints for running the below code in Laravel,

Below is the vendor code, which I have installed with composer, and if I run  `php ..pathto/./websocket_client.php` it prints the output in the terminal.

https://github.com/upstox/upstox-php/tree/master/examples/websocket/market_data
https://github.com/upstox/upstox-php/blob/master/examples/websocket/market_data/websocket_client.php

But my question is how can I run this php script in Laravel controller, I mean when I open the route this websocket_client.php script should run and I get data in JSON format to render in view.

Also in this code, how can we send value to instrument_key

```
    // Message payload to send to the server
    $data = [
        "guid" => "someguid",
        "method" => "sub",
        "data" => [
            "mode" => "full",
            "instrumentKeys" => ["NSE_FO|53983"]
        ]
    ];
```

Comment: Have you tried copy-pasting the code into your controller?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, Yes i did and its little bit worked, but as this is continues updates, PHP is failed in 30-60 seconds, so I moved this to job, but I am not sure if this is correct to way to get websocket data in job!

Comment: Your question is supposed to show the code that you've tried, and an explanation of what the problem is or why it does not work.  Edit your question, add your code, describe the problem.